# Java Mail Authentication Failed Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a problem when using JavaMail

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials ru12-20020a17090b2bcc00b001cb6527ca39sm4977241pjb.0 - gsmtp
```

My config on application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username={my email}
spring.mail.password={my password}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

I have read some solutions like "Turn on Less secure apps" on Settings account.google.com but that is old articles, now google no longer allows to use this feature.

I dont know how to fix it?

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.testConnection(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:398) ~[spring-context-support-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.mail.MailHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MailHealthIndicator.java:42) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:77) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:40) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:130) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:95) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:66) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:71) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:61) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) [spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) [spring-boot-actuator-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_311]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_311]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_311]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_311]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_311]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_311]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_311]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) [na:1.8.0_311]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_311]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [na:1.8.0_311]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
```

Comment: Have you read what it says on https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials as suggested in the error message?

Comment: yes, I doing follow that but it'sstill failed authentication

Comment: What exactly did you "follow"? Be specific about what you tried.

Comment: You might need `spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true` as well

Comment: These days, Google allows you to generate specific credentials for apps. This is superior to using 'your own' account credentials

Comment: Google has turn off by default this option. previously its working we can able to ON. Some apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology, which makes your account vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps, which we recommend, or turn it on if you want to use them despite the risks. Google will automatically turn this setting OFF if it’s not being used.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:
Step 1: Create app password on google account

- follow link: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Step 2: Add generated password to application.properties

- spring.mail.password={generated password}

Step 3: try again